# Entity Framework truncating decimal places when updating table

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2019

I have a table with a `decimal(18, 3)` column. The table maps to a class with the corresponding `decimal` property.

I change the value of the property to, e.g. 0.035, and this is the command that is generated by EF to update the column:

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[mytable]
SET [mycolumn] = @0
WHERE ([id] = @1)
',N'@0 decimal(18,2),@1 int',@0=3,@1=3
```

I need the scale to be up to 3 decimal places (which I'm doing) but it gets truncated to 2 on upadte.

Why is this happening and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Which version of EF are you using? How is your Entity class defined? e.g.: from .NET 6 there's a new `[Precision(precision, scale)]` attribute on poco properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call `HasColumnType("decimal(18,3)")` or avoid invoking the `HasColumnType()` in your `OnModelCreating()` method where you are configuring each property like this:

```
  entity.Property(e => e.mycolumn)
    .HasColumnType("decimal")
    .HasDefaultValueSql("00.000");
```

The EF uses a scale of 2 by default.

Comment: `HasColumnType("decimal(18, 3)")` must be changed to `HasPrecision(18, 3)` and then everything works as expected.